# Error "cannot be invited" when trying to reinvite someone to a GitHub organisation

Tags: github, invite

I have a new GitHub organisation (free, private) to which I invited a colleague. They mistakenly cancelled the email invitation they recieved and asked me to resend the invite.

However, when I do so (using the same email address I had used before), GitHb responds with:

> Sorry,user@email.com cannot be invited to MyPrivateOrg

The account is not part of a different Enterprise-type organisation in GitHub. We have also tried deleting his account from GitHub.

Does anyone have any suggestions?